# psftp -F config file

Tags: proxy, putty, sftp

Is there an equivalent `-F` option in the `psftp` (the one bundled with Putty)?

I am trying to connect to a VM that requires using a ProxyCommand.

```
Host *.<domain_here>
User kapitanluffy
ProxyCommand plink.exe <proxy_command_here>
```

I checked the [sftp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sftp) docs and the [psftp](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) docs. It seemed like `psftp` does not have that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a putty session and specify the proxy in it.  Then use

```
psftp.exe -load <session name>
```

Answer (score 0):

PSFTP now has `proxycmd` option

> -proxycmd command
>
> Instead of making a TCP connection, use command as a proxy; network
> traffic will be redirected to the standard input and output of
> command. command must be a single word, so is likely to need quoting
> by the shell.
>
> The special strings %host and %port in command will be replaced by the
> hostname and port number you want to connect to; to get a literal
> % sign, enter %%.
>
> Backslash escapes are also supported, such as sequences like \n being
> replaced by a literal newline; to get a literal backslash, enter
> \. (Further escaping may be required by the shell.)
>
> (See the main PuTTY manual for full details of the supported %- and
> backslash-delimited tokens, although most of them are probably not
> very useful in this context.)

[Source](https://www.mankier.com/1/psftp)